# Fazer mouseout uma unica vez

Tags: javascript

Gostaria de saber como posso fazer este script funcionar uma unica vez, pois não consigo fazê-lo:

```
// intenção de sair
function addEvent(obj, evt, fn) {
    if (obj.addEventListener) {
        obj.addEventListener(evt, fn, false);
    }
    else if (obj.attachEvent) {
        obj.attachEvent("on" + evt, fn);
    }
}

// gatilho 
addEvent(document, 'mouseout', function(evt) {

    if (evt.toElement == null && evt.relatedTarget == null ) {
        $('#lightbox_overlay').slideDown();
    };

});

// fechando o popup           
$('#lightbox_overlay, #close').on('click', function(event) { 
    $('.lightbox').slideUp();                            
});
```

Comment: Coloquei e não deu certo


 
if($('#lightbox_overlay').is(":visible")) return;
    addEvent(document, 'mouseout', function(evt) {

    if (evt.toElement == null && evt.relatedTarget == null ) {
        $('#lightbox_overlay').slideDown();
    }
});

Comment: Tentei assim também e nao funcionou

addEvent(document, 'mouseout', function(evt) {
    if($('#lightbox_overlay').is(":visible")) return; {
        $('#lightbox_overlay').slideDown();
    }

Comment: Vc quer que o `obj.addEventListener(evt, fn, false);` role só uma vez?

Comment: isso mesmo, apenas uma unica vez, quando o mouse sair, aparecer uma unica vez. Ja tentei usar o .one() do Jquery mas nao rolou.

Comment: Tente trocando o mouseout por mouseleave com o código que falei.

Comment: Dá uma olhada: https://jsfiddle.net/96z8dp3n/

Comment: este é o meu : https://jsfiddle.net/albertobrasilbr/jxq7muat/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usando a opção `{once: true}` indica que o evento será disparado no máximo 1 vez antes de ser automaticamente removido ([documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#Parameters)):

```
obj.addEventListener(evt, fn, {once : true});
```

Infelizmente o IE11 não dá suporte, mas é suportado por 93% dos navegadores no Brasil e 86% global ([veja no Can I Use](https://caniuse.com/#feat=once-event-listener)).

Comment: Deu certo ! Funcionou ! Quando vc sinaliza com o once : true (somente aquela vez) ele irá rodar de fato somente aquela vez. A instrução fica armazenada em algum cache do navegador ? Te pergunto isso, porque após realizar a função esta única vez, ao sair com o mouse da janela do navegador, a ação de fato não irá se repetir, porém não sei fica algum resquicio no cache ou não. Valeu pela a ajuda da instrução ! 

https://jsfiddle.net/albertobrasilbr/jxq7muat/17/

Comment: Não sei dizer, mas creio que o JS destrói o evento.

Comment: Valeu pela a ajuda !